# Having issues with PHP File Upload

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file to my site but for some odd reason its not working. The exists=true is triggering so this means it should be working right? Its giving me the $error=true;. Below is my code:

HTML:

```
<input size="30" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="profile_icon" id="register-profile_icon" class="elgg-input-file" type="file">
```

PHP:

```
$profile_icon = $_FILES["profile_icon"];
if($profile_icon){
    $exists=true;
}
$error = false;
if(empty($profile_icon["name"])){
    register_error(elgg_echo("profile_manager:register_pre_check:missing", array("profile_icon")));
    $error = true;
}
```

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` belongs in `<form>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$_FILES["profile_icon"]["tmp_path"]` for file path.

`$_FILES["profile_icon"]` This will contains arrays of values like name, tmp_path, type, size etc.

On another note you need to add `enctype` attribute to your `<form>`.

And there is function available for moving upload function `move_uploaded_file();`